# MySQL или MYSQLi

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Что лучше? Что безопаснее? И вообще стоит ли?

Comment: > Что лучше?

mysqli.

> И вообще стоит ли?

Нет, не стоит, стоит PDO через обертку любимого фреймворка, от себя могу посоветовать Doctrine как решение на любой случай жизни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

юзай PDO.
А в использование ORM, AR - есть как + так и -.
Да и в большинстве случаев пожирает память